# Auto inserted strange characters in wp post

Tags: posts, block-editor

I am facing a strange error on my site. Whenever I publish or update the post, some of my content just replaced by other random characters. Here is an example post :

**Original Content:**

> त्यसमा पनि प्रतिपक्षी दलका नेताले चोचोमोचो सुनिन्छ। प्रतिपक्षको काम
> अहिले त्यो होइन,' उनले भने, 'जसरी सरकार चलाउनेलाई जनता र संविधानले
> जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ त्यसैगरी प्रतिपक्षीलाई पनि जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ

**Replaced Content:**

> त्यसमा पनि प्रतिपक्ष%Eो काम अहिले त्यो होइन,' उनले भने, 'जसरी सरकार
> चलाउनेलाई जनता र संविधानले जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ त्यसैगरी प्रतिपक्षीलाई
> पनि जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ ।

- WP Version: 5.5.1
- PHP Version: 7.2

I am using classic editor for writing this content. And the error occurs whenever I update the post with the classic editor.
After I got this issue, I switched back to Gutenberg and tried updating the post, this also is giving me an error.

Here is the gutenberg response i got from the network tab:

```
code: "rest_invalid_json"
data: {status: 400, json_error_code: 3,…}
json_error_code: 3
json_error_message: "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"
status: 400
message: "Invalid JSON body passed."
```

The request payload is:

```
{"id":64851,"content":"<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>काठमाडौँ — कांग्रेस केन्द्रीय सदस्य तथा सांसद गगन थापाले यो सरकारले २०७९ मा हुने आम निर्वाचन निष्पक्ष गराउनेमा आफू विश्वस्त नभएको बताएका छन् । सामाजिक लोकतन्त्र अध्ययन केन्द्रले गरेको वागमती प्रदेशको भर्चुअल बैठकमा बोल्दै थापाले भने, 'मलाई यो कम्युनिष्ट सरकारले स्वच्छ र निष्पक्ष निष्पक्ष निर्वाचन गराउँछ भन्नेमा विश्वास छैन । यो कम्बोडियामा हुनसेनले गराएको निर्वाचनजस्तो हुनसक्छ । पहिले वामदेवले गराएको चुनाव सम्झिनुस्, त्यस्तै हुनसक्छ ।'</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>उनले सरकारलाई स्वच्छ र निष्पक्ष निर्वाचन गराउन बाध्य पार्नेगरी कांग्रेसले काम गर्नुपर्ने पनि बताए । यसका लागि कांग्रेसले प्रतिपक्षीको भूमिका राम्रोसँग निर्वाह गर्नुपर्ने पनि बताए । 'तर हाम्रो पार्टीले र नेतृत्वले प्रतिपक्षीको भूमिका प्रभावकारी ढंगले निर्वाह गर्न सकेको छैन,' उनले भने । थापाले आफ्नो पार्टीको नेतृत्वले विभिन्न नियुक्ति र लेनदेनमा सरकारसँगै लसपस गरेको देखिएको पनि बताए ।</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>'अब संवैधानिक निकायमा नियुक्तिको कुरा छ । त्यसमा पनि प्रतिपक्षी दलका नेताले चोचोमोचो सुनिन्छ। प्रतिपक्ष काम अहिले त्यो होइन,' उनले भने, 'जसरी सरकार चलाउनेलाई जनता र संविधानले जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ त्यसैगरी प्रतिपक्षीलाई पनि जिम्मेवारी दिएको छ । हामी त्यसबाट चुकिरहेको जनताले बताइरहेका छन् ।'</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>'सरकारका असफलता देखिएका छन् । कोरोनाविरुद्ध लड्ने कुरामा सरकारको असफलतादेखि भ्रष्टचारका काण्डहरुले जनता सरकारसँग निराश छन् तर हामीसँग पनि खुशी छैनन् । हामीले जनताका आवाज उठाउनेगरी काम गर्न सकेका छैनौं,' उनले भने ।</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>पार्टीका बरिष्ठ नेता रामचन्द्र पौडेलले भ्रष्टाचारको विरोधमा जारी गरेका दुई विज्ञप्तिले तरंग ल्याएको उल्लेख गर्दै भने, 'संसदमा नरहनुभएका पार्टीका एकजना नेताले रेल र अख्तियारबारे जारी गर्नु भएका विज्ञप्तिले पार्टी पंक्तिदेखि मिडियासम्ममा तरंग ल्यायो । यसरी नै संसदमा प्रतिपक्षी दलको नेता र सिंगो पार्टी पंङ्तिले यस्ता विषयमा बोल्न सकेको भए कस्तो तर‌ंग आउँथ्यो होला ?'</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>उनले कांग्रेस पार्टी कुनै बेला सामाजिक अभियानका रुपमा रहेको तर अहिले पार्टीले त्यो स्वरुप गुमाएको पनि बताए । 'हामी सबै कुरामा कांग्रेस खत्तमै भयो, कांग्रेस पहिलेजस्तो भएन भनेर धेरै आत्मआलोचना गर्नु जरुरी छैन तर हामीले सामाजिक अभियानका रुपमा पनि पार्टीलाई जनतासँग जोड्नु आवश्यक छ ।</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>आज काठमान्डुमा यत्रा मान्छे कोरोनाका कारण सडकमा आएका छन् । खान नपाउने भएका छन् । घरबार गुमेको छ । ती मान्छेलाई हाम्रो जिल्ला र महानगर कमिटी जोडिन सक्दैन ? तिनलाई सहयोग गर्न सक्दैन ?' उनले प्रश्न गरे । उनले बीपीको पालमा जस्तो जनतासँग संवाद गर्ने नेतृत्वको अहिले पार्टीमा अभाव भएको पनि बताए ।</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>उनले यो संविधानबारे धेरै गनगन गर्नुको पनि अर्थ नरहेको बताए । 'गिरिजाप्रसाद कोइरालाको नेतृत्वमा हिजोको हिंसा अन्त्य गरेर शान्ति सम्झौता गरेको र संविधान सभा चुनाव गराएकोमा गर्व गर्ने, सुशील कोइरालाको नेतृत्वमा संविधान जारी गरेकोमा गर्व गर्ने अनि फेरि अहिले त्यही संविधानका विषयमा गनगन गर्ने ?' उनले प्रश्न गरे, 'यो हामीले बनाएको संविधान हो । यसमा केही कमी कमजोरी छन् भने त्यसलाई सच्च्याउने हो । कतिपय कुराहरु समयसँगै सुध्रिदै/प्रष्टिदै जान्छन् ।'</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>उनले आगामि १४ औं महाधिवेशनमा पार्टीलाई एकढिक्का बनाउने एजेन्डा रहेको भन्दै यसका एउटै उपाय भएको बताए- विधानको पालना । 'सभापति विधानअनुसार चल्नुभएको छैन । उहाँ बलमिच्याइले चलिरहनु भएको छ । पार्टीको विधान नमान्ने सभापतिले प्रधानमन्त्रीले संविधान मानेन्न भन्न मिल्छ ?' उनले प्रश्न गरे । एकपछि अर्को विधान मिच्ने काम भएकाले अविश्वास पैदा भएको पनि उनले बताए ।</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->"}
```

I haven't changed any encoding format everything is default as of WordPress installation.

Comment: Is your database using the correct encoding to support those characters? Keep in mind that it isn't enough to declare the encoding you want in `wp-config.php` as that won't change the tables if they've already been created. Also do you have a smaller example? I'm not familiar with those characters so it's difficult to identify which parts are missing

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with the block editor; try using the [Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/) contains a newer version of the block editor and if you still experience the same error; try posting in the [forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/how-to-and-troubleshooting/).